# Can't I use code to get out of a specific app?

Tags: android, kotlin

`

```
class prohibitionservice : Service() {

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val youtubeUsageLimit = 15 * 60 * 1000  // 15분 (밀리초 단위)

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForegroundService()
    }

    private fun startForegroundService() {
        createNotificationChannel()

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Youtube Control Service")
            .setContentText("15분 이상 사용함")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .build()

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

        handler.postDelayed(youtubeCheckRunnable, youtubeUsageLimit.toLong())
    }

    private val youtubeCheckRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (isYoutubeAppRunning()) {
                exitYoutubeApp()
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, youtubeUsageLimit.toLong())
        }
    }

    private fun isYoutubeAppRunning(): Boolean {
        val packageName = "com.google.android.youtube"

        val activityManager = getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val runningAppProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses

        for (processInfo in runningAppProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.processName == packageName) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun exitYoutubeApp() {
        val packageName = "com.google.android.youtube"

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "YoutubeControlChannel"
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Youtube Control Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager: NotificationManager? =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

An app that uses this code is designed to work as a foreground service when you restart your phone. If you restart your phone, this app will notify you that it has a foreground service. I don't think there's a problem with starting the foreground service. However, if this app watches YouTube for more than 15 minutes, it performs the action of leaving the app. Does this violate Android policy? As soon as this app starts the foreground service, a warning appears on the screen saying it was forced to shut down...

Originally, I included a code that did an action (force youtube shut down) to shut down the YouTube app, but I deleted it. And yet it's like this.